# .Net GMap slice map into smaller pieces

Tags: c#, gmap.net

I have problem with my .Net GMap in offline, it takes too much time and space to download all the tiles in 4 zoom levels from 13 till 18. So I figured out that maybe I can split(slice) the country map with 1'000x1'000 lines which gives 1'000'000 pieces(tiles) an look in each tile if there is placed marker and download only that tile in those levels. But the main problem is that I don't know how to split(slice) the country map virtually or something like that. Maybe someone has some ideas or already have done something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Since the markers are derived from the GMapMarker class you can loop through all the markers in your markers collection object.

Each marker will have a Position property. Since you now know the Latitude and Longitude of the marker you can derive the X and Y values of the tile with the FromLatLngToPixel and FromPixelToTileXY functions. In the C# example below you will be able to get the X and Y tile values from the *tile* object.

```
var px   = MainMap.MapProvider.Projection.FromLatLngToPixel(marker.Position.Lat, marker.Position.Lng, (int)gmap.Zoom);
var tile = MainMap.MapProvider.Projection.FromPixelToTileXY(px);
```

Then to get the tile from the server, look at how the TilePrefetcher class handles the X, Y value to get the tile. Look at the *worker_DoWork* eventhandler in the TilePrefetcher class.